# How to run a python script from inside a powershell script with a windows scheduled task?

Tags: python, powershell, scheduled-tasks

So my issue goes like this, I have a powershell script (lets call it getter.ps1) that gets some data and passes it to a python script (lets call it finder.py). The powershell script looks like this:

```
$data = get-data
python $data finder.py
```

When I run the powershell script from a powershell window by doing this:

```
.\getter.ps1
```

It runs fine, the powershell portion does it's job and passes the data over to the python script which runs and returns its data.

However, when I try to run the powershell script on a scheduled task, only the powershell portion runs, the python portion just does nothing. Sure im just missing something obvious here, any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Try to pass absolute path for the .py file: `python $data $PSScriptRoot\finder.py`

Comment: @zett42 Yessir that fixed it, you are the man. I kinda had a feeling I was overlooking something easy like that too :(